# X tunneling issue from remote machine

Tags: ssh, x11

I am trying tunnel an x window. If a do:

```
user@local: ssh -X user@remote  xclock
```

it works. However if i log in to the machine first and then start the program it fails.

```
user@local: ssh -X user@remote

user@remote: xclock
No protocol specified
Error: Can't open display: :0
```

What went wrong?

**Edit**

I checked the `$DISPLAY` variable on the remote:

```
user@local: ssh -X user@remote "echo $DISPLAY"
:0.0
```

setting it to the same value on the remote after login doesn't work. Setting `$DISPLAY` to `:10.0` as suggested works.

```
user@local: ssh -X user@remote
user@remote: DISPLAY=:10.0 xclock
```

I still don't understand why I need different $DISPLAY values for the interactive and the non interactive session.

Comment: Check that the variable *DISPLAY* be correctly set to *localhost:10.0*. If it is not, *export DISPLAY=localhost:10.0* , then try *xclock* again.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae great that works. But why do I need 'DISPLAY' to be `10.0` instead of `0.0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that the variable *DISPLAY* be correctly set to *localhost:10.0*. If it is not,

```
export DISPLAY=localhost:10.0
```

, then try *xclock* again.

> But why do I need 'DISPLAY' to be 10.0 instead of 0.0?

The *X server* (or *X Window*, or *X11*) is exactly that, a server, waiting for apps to connect to it in order to display them. That occurs on your pc, where apps connect to the X server via a socket located in */tmp*, typically called */tmp/.X11-unix*. However, like all servers, *X11* can be contacted from remote pcs, and display graphucally applications which run on remote pcs.

However, this ability carries many security risks, so that opening your X11 server to remote applications is very difficult (you need to specify the same option at least three times, in different configuration files).

Now enter *ssh*, which instead makes this secure: it is the *-Y/-X* option of *ssh* which handles securely (also by encrypting traffic) all details of opening your local X11 server to the remote application. However, when you want to display the *remote* xclock locally, you must instruct the remote app that the X11 server to be contacted is not its own X11 server, but it is one on a distant pc (the one from which you started the *ssh* session). So *xclock* must send its output **not** to a local socket in */tmp* but to a network port (it is *127.0.0.1:6010*, which *ssh* mercifully shortens to *localhost:10*), from which *ssh* will take care of sending it back to your local pc, where eventually the output is graphically displayed.

If you do not like the different ssh connections (you might have multiple ones) to be separated by *10* units, as in *localhost:10.0, localhost:20.0, ...*) you should change the statement

```
X11DisplayOffset 10
```

in */etc/ssh/sshd_config* to whatever you like (though I cannot see any reason for this, to be honest).

It is this statement that causes the remote displays to be available **not** on port *6000* (which would be *localhost:0.0*), but on port *6010*. You can check this yourself:

```
$ ssh -Y vps
Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
Last login: Mon Apr 17 02:47:42 2017 from 
root@vps:~# ss -lntp | grep 6010
LISTEN     0      0                 127.0.0.1:6010                     *:*      users:(("sshd",16172,8))
LISTEN     0      0                       ::1:6010                    :::*      users:(("sshd",16172,7))
```